# Retrieve object based on its array position in Firebase

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase for a project and need to return an object based on its array position.

In the documentation, I've found explanations for returning and listing the full array of objects, child properties found within parent objects, etc, but nothing for returning objects by position in their parent array.

In other words, if I have a Firebase array of dinos:

```
"dinos" :
    {
      "lambeosaurus": {
        "height" : 2.1,
        "length" : 12.5,
        "weight": 5000
      },
      "stegosaurus": {
        "height" : 4,
        "length" : 9,
        "weight" : 2500
      }
    }
```

is there a way for me to return the object stored at dinos[1]?

Comment: the closest answer i've found has been in this blog post, but it doesn't really explain how to locate an object. https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-04-28-best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Comment: The example you have posted does not look like an array - an array would use square brackets [ ] around the collection and wrap each item in curly brackets to create objects, with lambeosaurus and stegosaurus resumably being name properties. Is this the data you put in, or what you got back out? As mentioned in unfollow's link, Firebase does manipulate the structure of the arrays...

Comment: It seems like Firebase takes JSON objects and converts them into object data structures containing "child" objects. i'm unsure on the exact nomenclature for the FB data structure, but shouldn't it still be possible to locate child objects based on their position in the parent object?

Comment: Yes, although the transformation does not look to have happened in this case - the dinos are referenced by a name rather than a zero based index, which implies that perhaps the blog you posted was not relevant (although it does not state what happens with key=> value arrays, did you post one of them?)

Comment: Have you checked out their follow-on post about synchronised arrays? https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-05-06-synchronized-arrays.html

Comment: This is how Firebase handles arrays: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase Firebase recommends strongly against using index-based arrays, since they don't scale well across multiple users/clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is interested, this approach worked. If anyone has feedback on how it can be refactored that would be great.

```
var userDict = {};    

function getUserList(){
   usersRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
     userDict = snapshot.val();
   for(i=0;  i < Object.keys(userDict).length; i++){
       console.log(Object.keys(userDict)[i]);//<---returns list of unique URLS
       console.log(userDict[Object.keys(userDict)[i]].dinos);
     }
  });
}
```

Comment: While this is an approach, it doesn't directly answer the initial question which was to return an object based on its array position. Kato is on point about not using arrays (we learned that lesson) but the bigger issue here is that this code becomes inefficient for large data sets. Imagine if the node contains a million children and each child has it's own set of data. This code reads the entire node at one time and iterates over a million records. That will not only fill up memory but also tie up the user interface. Would it make sense to just directly read the node of data you want?

Comment: Oh... Dictionaries have no guarantee of order so technically the position of each object could change from read to read so the 'index' could be different each time. Also, (and someone check me on this) reading in  node data from Firebase doesn't have a guaranteed order so the objects contained in the snapshot could be in different positions as well.

Answer (score 0):

The example you've cited here is about [ordering data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries), and it's extremely unclear how you've gone from this to trying to force the unique ids for each record into array indices.

First answer: [don't use arrays in distributed data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase)

Second answer: The field used in the `orderBy()` is the index. Thus, if I were to utilize the example from that same document:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs");
ref.orderByChild("height").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key() + " was " + snapshot.val().height + " meters tall");
});
```

Then to change the ordering of a dinosaur, I would change the `height` field to a different value. For a leaderboard, we would `orderByChild('score')` or, for a list of chat messages, `orderByChild('timestamp')`. Those fields would then control ordering of the JSON hashes (i.e. objects with keys, which are inherently unordered in JavaScript and JSON, not arrays).

Comment: Not trying to force uniques, sorry if that was unclear. I'm looking to find object positions. I actually came up with a solve. Check below.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to simply change the structure of the data and query for the index you want.

Given a dataset (yeah, poor form on the 'indexes')

```
"dinos" :
    {
       "0": {
        "name": "lambeosaurus":
        "height" : 2.1,
        "length" : 12.5,
        "weight": 5000
      },
       "1": {
        "name": "stegosaurus":
        "height" : 4,
        "length" : 9,
        "weight" : 2500
      }
    }
```

You now have a lot of flexibility:

If you know the 'index' number 0, 1 etc, you can directly read in the child. So to get dino at 'index' #1:

```
Firebase *allDinosRef = [rootRef childByAppendingPath@"dinos"];
Firebase *aDinoRef = [allDinosRef childByAppendingPath@"1"];

[aDinoRef observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
            //do something with the dino index #1 data
        }];
```

You could also query for a specific dinosaur name and then get it's parent so you would know it's index.

An alternative is a leverage a different structure

```
"dinos" :
        {
           auto_generated_id: {
            "name": "lambeosaurus":
            "height" : 2.1,
            "length" : 12.5,
            "weight": 5000
            "index": "0"
          },
           auto_generated_id: {
            "name": "stegosaurus":
            "height" : 4,
            "length" : 9,
            "weight" : 2500
            "index": "1"
          }
        }
```

auto_generated_id is a Firebase id that would be generated by childByAutoId

Using this structure, you could compose a simple query to get the dino at the index # you are interested in.

```
FQuery *allDinos = [rootRef queryOrderedByChild:@"index"];
FQuery *specificDino = [allDinos queryEqualToValue:@"1"];

[specificDino observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
  //do something with Dino at 'index' 1
}];
```

This provides some additional flexibility in that you can easily re-order dino's insert etc without writing out a whole bunch of data - just changing indexes would do.